Oracle SQL query need
I am using this query to get the month wise count.
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
    COUNT(your_id_column) AS record_count
FROM
    your_table_name
WHERE
    your_date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE('start_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('end_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY
    TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'YYYY-MM');

But output coming like this.
JAN-23 34
FEB-23 45
MAR-23 89

But I need like this
JAN-23  FEB-23  MAR-23
  34       45     89

Please suggest

A SQL query results in a table with the columns you defined in the query (and as many rows as match your criteria). In other words: You must know which months the query shall produce in order to get month columns. If you do, then look up pivot or conditional aggregation.

TO_DATE('start_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD') is not valid as 'start_date' is a string literal and not a date.

It is generally advisable to reformat the results outside of SQL (presumably, your reporting layer / application). SQL uses the normalised form (the one you have, but don't want) for many very good reasons, learn to work with it, not against it.

If you know which months you require then use conditional aggregation to pivot the rows into columns:
SELECT COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN your_date_column >= DATE '2023-01-01'
         AND  your_date_column <  DATE '2023-02-01'
         THEN your_id_column
         END
       ) AS JAN_2023,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN your_date_column >= DATE '2023-02-01'
         AND  your_date_column <  DATE '2023-03-01'
         THEN your_id_column
         END
       ) AS FEB_2023,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN your_date_column >= DATE '2023-03-01'
         AND  your_date_column <  DATE '2023-04-01'
         THEN your_id_column
         END
       ) AS MAR_2023
FROM   your_table_name
WHERE  your_date_column >= TRUNC(start_date)
AND    your_date_column <  TRUNC(end_date) + 1;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (your_date_column, your_id_column, start_date, end_date) AS
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', LEVEL, DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-04-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 34 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-02-01', LEVEL, DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-04-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 45 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-03-01', LEVEL, DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-04-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 89;

Outputs:



JAN_2023
FEB_2023
MAR_2023




34
45
89




Alternatively, if you want to pivot a number of months to a fixed number of columns (but don't know which they are):
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(your_date_column)) AS month_num,
         TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS month,
         your_id_column
  FROM   your_table_name
  WHERE  your_date_column >= TRUNC(start_date)
  AND    your_date_column <  TRUNC(end_date) + 1
)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(your_id_column) AS cnt,
  MAX(month) AS name
  FOR month_num IN (
    1 AS MONTH1,
    2 AS MONTH2,
    3 AS MONTH3
  )
);

Which outputs:



MONTH1_CNT
MONTH1_NAME
MONTH2_CNT
MONTH2_NAME
MONTH3_CNT
MONTH3_NAME




34
JAN-23
45
FEB-23
89
MAR-23



fiddle

Its pretty much straight forward, you can use 'PIVOT' function to get the output you looking for. Here is the sample Code.
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'MON-YY') AS month,
    your_id_column
  FROM 
    your_table_name
  WHERE 
    your_date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE('start_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('end_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(your_id_column)
  FOR month IN (
    'JAN-23', 'FEB-23', 'MAR-23'  -- add more months as needed
  )
);

Dynamic SQL to generate the 'PIVOT' statement.
Dynamic SQL
